# SQL Server Express DataBase changes saving

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Why my changes done on the SQLServer Express dataBase are not saved in runtime ?? when I make an insertion in any table, and read the table after that, I don't find my insertion. But, when I close the application and open it again, I find the new data inserted !!!

NB: The DataBase is not in my project folder, it's in another folder and referenced by a connectionString from my project.

I'm using C# language in Visual Studio 2010.

======> UPDATE:

Here is a part of my code:

```
 public void AddUser(Utilisateur user)
    {
        Connect();
        var userInsertion = "INSERT INTO [User](Name, LastName, Phone, Mail, Password, Grade, Office, Initial)VALUES('" + user.Name + "','" + user.LastName + "','" + user.Phone + "','" + user.Mail + "','" + user.Password + "','" + user.Grade + "','" + user.Office + "','" + user.Initial + "')";
        SqlCommand userInsertionCommand = new SqlCommand(userInsertion, connection);
        userInsertionCommand.Transaction= connection.BeginTransaction();
        var result = userInsertionCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        userInsertionCommand.Transaction.Commit();
        userInsertionCommand.Dispose();
        Disconnect();
    }
```

Here is my ConnectionString to the DataBase:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
   <configSections>
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDataBasePath" connectionString="Data Source=MyComputer\SQLSERVEREXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually reading from the database after the change and not some application cache?

Comment: Show us your code. You're probably keeping the connection open and never flushing the session.

Comment: I'll update my post just now

Comment: Where's the part that you're reading the database?

Comment: reading the database? you mean selecting the searched row ?